# Sass 3.4.1 escaping a "\270e" into "\\270e" which breaks a font icon

Tags: sass

In my Sass, I have a variable like this:

```
$icon-pencil: \270e;
```

Then, later I have this:

```
i.icon-pencil:before {
    content: "#{$entypo-icon-pencil}";
    height: inherit;
}
```

(Yes, I know that I don't need interpolation there. I actually have a function there, but I'm simplifying to make the question easier to follow.)

That outputs this:

```
i.icon-pencil:before {
    content: "\\270e";
    height: inherit;
}
```

The extra slash makes it just output the text instead of the HTML entity (i.e., the pencil icon).

Why is it being escaped? What can I do to prevent it?

I found [this comment](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/659#issuecomment-53775335) which seems like my issue, but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I don't understand what you think SO can do about this.  This is a known issue, the only thing you can do is wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: Well, for example, is there a way to create an "unescape" function or something as a workaround?

Comment: For the time being, I've rolled back to Sass 3.3.x as a workaround, but still going to leave this open in case anyone has any clever fixes.