# how to preserve quoted chars in sass

Tags: sass, node-sass, gulp-ruby-sass

How can i preserve or escape paths in sass. We have strings like `"Page\Footer\CustomBar\Logo"` which are (wrongly) transformed internally to `"Page\footer\customBarLogo"` How can we preserve the ascii format? We tried with dart sass and ruby sass.

`Page\Footer\CustomBar\Logo` would be expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit I didn't found any built-in way to do what you need. It seems that backslashes are hard to manipulate with SASS. However, here is how I managed to get your path:

```
@function createPath($path...) {
   $finalPath: null;

   @each $el in $path {
      @if($finalPath) {
         // Do not add the slashes at the beginning of the string
         $finalPath: $finalPath + "\\";
      };

      $finalPath: $finalPath + $el;
   }

   // At this point, $finalPath = "Page\\Footer\\CustomBar\\Logo"
   @return unquote("\"#{$finalPath}\"");
}
```

Calling `createPath('Page', 'Footer', 'CustomBar', 'Logo');` will return `"Page\Footer\CustomBar\Logo"`.

Honestly, I can't explain how the `unquote` works, I found the solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675344/9718056).

Comment: Thank you Arkellys for your help but that is not really a solution to our problem since we inject a data structure into our sass code with strings. Of course we could have an array for this property but then i guess it makes more sense to have two backslashes which works fine. I will see if i find some more input on that issue in the next days. Thank you.

Comment: @Rob Oh okay, I think you should edit your question with more details then. :)